# Why is the first pointerDragged location depending on the size of the Form?

Tags: codenameone

I noticed some strange behaviour with dragging Switch instances and such. To investigate this I created a small non-scrollable Form derivate which contains a Component derivate with a custom paint method which draws a round rect in the component size and a green crosshair for a pointerPressed location and a blue crosshair for the first pointerDragged location.

Testing using the Simulator with the Desktop Skin one gets views like that dragging within the custom component:

[image] [image] [image]

So it appears that the first pointerDragged location one gets is farther away from the pointerPressed location the larger the Form is.

That is a problem whereever pointerDragged events are required. For example with a Switch component this is very noticeable on an iPad in landscape.

Why is that? Is it a bug or a feature?

Here is the code:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.setScrollable(false);
    Command commandReload = new Command("Reload") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aActionEvent) {
            start();
        }
    };
    hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(commandReload);
    Component component = new Component() {
        Point pointPressed = null, pointDraggedFirst = null;

        @Override
        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(120, 120);
        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) {
            aGraphics.setColor(0x000000);
            aGraphics.drawRoundRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 20, 20);
            if (null != pointPressed) {
                aGraphics.setColor(0x00C000);
                aGraphics.drawLine(getX(), pointPressed.getY() - getAbsoluteY(), getX() + getWidth() - 1, pointPressed.getY() - getAbsoluteY());
                aGraphics.drawLine(pointPressed.getX() - getAbsoluteX(), getY(), pointPressed.getX() - getAbsoluteX(), getY() + getHeight() - 1);
                if (null != pointDraggedFirst) {
                    aGraphics.setColor(0x0000ff);
                    aGraphics.drawLine(getX(), pointDraggedFirst.getY() - getAbsoluteY(), getX() + getWidth() - 1, pointDraggedFirst.getY() - getAbsoluteY());
                    aGraphics.drawLine(pointDraggedFirst.getX() - getAbsoluteX(), getY(), pointDraggedFirst.getX() - getAbsoluteX(), getY() + getHeight() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {
            pointPressed = new Point(x, y);
        }
        @Override
        public void pointerDragged(int x, int y) {
            if (null == pointDraggedFirst) {
                pointDraggedFirst = new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
            pointPressed = null;
            pointDraggedFirst = null;
        }
    };
    hi.add(FlowLayout.encloseLeftMiddle(component));
    hi.add(new Label("X") {
        int width = 0, height = 0;
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) {
            if (width != hi.getWidth() || height != hi.getHeight()) {
                width = hi.getWidth();
                height = hi.getHeight();
                Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> setText("Form Width/Height: " + hi.getWidth() + "/" + hi.getHeight()));
            }
            super.paint(aGraphics);
        }
    });
    hi.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Some devices send pointer dragged immediately and create an effect where it's hard to distinguish between a click and a drag. So we have a threshold composed from screen percentage and event count during which we block native drag events.

You can shorten this time by overriding `getDragRegionStatus` to indicate your interest in specific drag events.

Comment: I see - in 'com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.hasDragStarted(int, int)'. A certain threshold makes sense but, but with big screen sizes this prevents dragging completely, at least for components which are smaller then the threshold. Have a look at Switch on large screens - the handle cannot be dragged then.

Comment: The issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2644 made me investigating this. I added a comment

Comment: That might be a bug in the component